# WooCommerce dashboard - highlight orders marked 'Local pickup'

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

In the WooCommerce backend, can you highlight the orders that have 'Local pickup" in the 'Ship to' column, via CSS?

Something like this (a yellow background, a border, any css):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPluq.jpg

I had to blur the order data, I hope it's clear what I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

    if( $order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup') ) 
    {   
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery("#post-<?php echo $post_id; ?>").css("background-color", "yellow");

    });
    </script>

    <?php

    }


}
```